# Opening terminal using python

Tags: python, terminal

Currently I've been creating just a small program. And one of the options is to start a counter.

Code for counter

```
from time import sleep
number = 0
while 1 == 1:
    sleep(1)
    print number
    number += 1
```

I want to be able to open this program in a new terminal window (Ubuntu) so I can keep the existing terminal open. Anyway to do this in python?

Thanks

Paul

**EDIT**
I think I figured out one way to run it in the same terminal so it works!

```
os.system('python counter.py')
```

I simply used that, I thought if I were to do that before, when I used CTRL + C it would close down both programs but this seems to of worked. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: why not create another terminal then run this python program? Or you can bring this python process to the background via `python your-script.py &`?

Comment: While I can just simply open a new terminal and start the program, I want this other script I'm making to launch it in a new terminal.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but you should simplify your if statement to "while 1:" or "While True:". It'll become cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Thank you pkacpzak! I'll do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper that launches your terminal and tells it to run your script. If you know which terminal you're using, this isn't too hard. For example, if you use [`multi-gnome-terminal`](http://multignometerm.sourceforge.net/web/doc/options.html):

```
#!/bin/sh
multi-gnome-terminal --use-factory --command /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
```

Now, every time you run that wrapper (with `sh ./wrapper`, or `/usr/local/bin/wrapper` if you `install -m755` it, or by double-clicking it, or whatever), it will open a new window (launching a new terminal process only if necessary) and run your script there.